# How to make a span tag to be centered from it's current elemental ( Like Youtube share button )

Tags: html, css, social-media, share-button

I am currently working on my share buttons and I am trying to make them act like the share buttons on YouTube do, when `a:hovered` a `span` elemental appears with a text "Facebook/Twitter/RSS" etc.

The span element width should be auto since "Facebook" and "RSS" contains a different amount of letters, and I don't want to set a fixed width.

I want the span element to appear in the "middle" of it's current element, check the [youtube share buttom](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbvdzQ7uVPc) for a hint.

I have come this far, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Kz2n2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<a href="#" title="share this" class="tooltip"><span title="share">share</span></a>
```

css:

```
.tooltip{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip:hover:after{
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 100%;
}

.tooltip:hover:before{
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 20px;
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

working jsfiddle:
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3HAaU/)

Comment: it's pretty cool, but still not centered ;), any solution for that ;D?

Comment: updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3HAaU/1/ or check this: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Answer (score 0):

With [jQuery UI Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style) you can make tooltips for your social icons.

Check out the [following example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kz2n2/9/), here is the jQuery UI Tooltip implemented.

```
$('.tooltip').tooltip();
```

The title tag on your `<a href='#'`>` is used as the text for your tooltip.

```
<a href="#.php" class="tooltip" title="RSS">#<span>RSS.</span></a>
```